# Explanation of rotational barrier in molecular physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, molecules

I remember that in my molecular physics lecture, I learned that rotating molecules have to pass a rotational barrier before they can dissociate, in contrast to only vibrating ones. 
Could someone give an intuitive argument as to why this barrier exists for rotations? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a diatomic, non-rotating molecule. In this case the potential energy $U(R)$ depends on the distance $R$ between the two atoms; this could be described for example by a Morse potential. For distances $R$ that are larger than the equilibrium bond length this potential is typically attractive.

If the molecule is rotating then the effect of the rotation can be absorbed into an [effective potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_potential)

$$
U_{\mathrm{eff}} (R) = U(R) + L^2 / (2 \mu R^2)
$$

where $L$ is the angular momentum and $\mu$ is the reduced mass. This new term is purely repulsive (unless the angular momentum is zero, i.e., this molecule is not rotating). Intuitively, this term gives rise to the centrifugal force that stretches the bond. The competition between the attractive $U(R)$ and the repulsive centrifugal potential can give rise in a barrier in $U_{\mathrm{eff}} (R)$.

[Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=IOqAB2NNZgsC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA332#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a link where you can read more about this effect.